# WebDriver get last calendar day

Tags: java, selenium, calendar, webdriver

I need to get the last day of current month in calendar: http://prntscr.com/7z506w

Here's the HTML code:

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td
                class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
            <td
                class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td
                class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
                <span class="ui-state-default">26</span>
            </td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
                <span class="ui-state-default">27</span>
            </td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
                <span class="ui-state-default">28</span>
            </td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
                <span class="ui-state-default">29</span>
            </td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null"
                title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
                <span class="ui-state-default">30</span>
            </td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over null ui-datepicker-today"
                onclick="DP_jQuery_1438322656964.datepicker._selectDay('#FormElement_date_289_input',6,2015, this);return false;">
                <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-hover"
                href="#">31</a>
            </td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled"/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And screenshot

---

[image]

So how to know that it is the last element in calendar, and fetch it in Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: Formatting of HTML code - added indentation

Comment: could you post the whole code for your table? Some lines are missing, maybe there lies the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is another td element at the end of your last row in the table you need to exclude the class that distinguishes this element from the others -> "ui-datepicker-other-month"

Given your example you can try:

```
WebElement lastDay = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//table//tr)[last()]//td[not (contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-other-month'))])[last()]"));
```

If you wanna see the 31:

```
System.out.println(lastDay.getText());
```

Comment: updated my answer, you need to find the last tr element first, then the last td element

Comment: it gave me "0" instead of "31"

Comment: what do you mean "it gave me"? what kind of code did you apply, if you provide this in your question, I might help you to get the right number. Because right now I only showed you how to get the last element of the HTML you provided. this td element itself holds other elements that hold you desired number.

Comment: I know, but in console I get number 0, not the last element

Comment: what are you writing to console? pls provide your code. AND did you provide the complete html code for your date-time-picker? maybe there is another td element below the last one you posted? that would explain the differences

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84796/discussion-between-drkthng-and-vitaliy-mckay).

Answer (score 0):

Here's all HTML table

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null" title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null" title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null" title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null" title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled null" title="Cannot choose a date earlier than a previous anchor task or the start date.">
<td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over null ui-datepicker-today" onclick="DP_jQuery_1438322656964.datepicker._selectDay('#FormElement_date_289_input',6,2015, this);return false;">
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-hover" href="#">31</a>
</td>
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled"/>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not an answer, but an update to your question. You can close it before someone downvotes it -> I updated your question and my answer. Cheers